# Why is jQuery UI dialog.('Close') firing too early?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to create a popup message in my app.  On success I want to open a dialog, animate it...and then close it.  I guess a better question should have been, "How do you create a timed popup in Jquery...but anyway when I run my code it appears that my dialog appears for just a split second.  If I remove the dialog('close') line it works up until that point.  Does jquery fire these commands in sequence or in parallel?

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "/Sales",
   data: { customer: [id] },
   success: function(msg) {
      $('#thanks').dialog('open');
      $('#thanks').animate({ backgroundColor: '#aa0000', color: '#fff', width: 500 }, 2000); 
      $('#thanks').dialog('close');
   }
});
```

Answer (score 5):

with lines the way you have it would work in almost synchronous. Try

```
 $('#thanks').dialog('open').animate({ backgroundColor: '#aa0000', color: '#fff', width: 500 }, 2000).dialog('close');
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to close the dialog in the callback from the *animate* function:

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "/Sales",
   data: { customer: [id] },
   success: function(msg) {
      $('#thanks').dialog('open');
      $('#thanks').animate({ backgroundColor: '#aa0000', color: '#fff', width: 500 }, 2000, "linear", function(){ $('#thanks').dialog('close'); }); 
   }
});
```

But I think you'd be better off using a plugin, such as [jGrowl](http://www.stanlemon.net/projects/jgrowl.html)?

Answer (score 0):

might not be waiting for the animate to finish. try adding a wait of 2000 in, or chaining the close.

Answer (score 0):

The `.dialog('close')` call isn't waiting for your animation. But do you really want to close the dialog right away, or shouldn't you rather wait for user input (i.e. a link/button click) to close it?